# Onboarding CIVICRM

Tags: configuration, evaluating-civicrm

My name is Nada Kartouch and I am helping thinkforward charity to find suitable CRM system to support their work.

The charity is based in London and looks after less-privileged teenagers to help them continue education and / or find decent jobs.

I think CIVICRM is a very suitable solution, therefore I would like to verify couple of points with you.

First:  To what extent we can configure contacts / contributions / events. As can we change the fields / names / relationship between items.

Second: would be possible to get a quote for hosting 25 to 30 accounts (as I read that you can help us do so with your partners)

Third: can you provide a quote as well if we need help in customising the solution.

Finally, let me thank you in advance for the great support and solution.

Warm regards 
Nada

Answer (score 2):

thanks for showing an interest in CiviCRM. Let me first explain that this 'forum' is a community thing, there is no 'CiviCRM' company which can give you a quote. You can however find a CiviCRM partner with this link: https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors. As you can see on the list there a a few partners based in the UK who might be able to help you. I am part of a partner organization in The Netherlands.

You can configure quite a lot in CiviCRM, but I am not sure what you mean when you say that you want to configure contacts, contributions and events. I can say that there are quite a few charities that do use CiviCRM for contact management, contributions and events so I would expect you should be able to do most of what you want.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Erik's answer I would also suggest that you look at the [documentation](https://book.civicrm.org/) to get an overview of CiviCRM and see what configuration is possible.  CiviCRM is very flexible.